# difficulty with column-column-line associations/manipulations

Tags: python, bash

Oh great and knowledgeable gurus of stackoverflow,

I'm trying to figure out an appropriate coding solution for my data processing algorithm and I'm stuck. I have 2 files (file1 and file2) with 4 columns in the following format:

```
0.23961 216185 518 LIRRTSI
0.156348 216185 338 NTGSPYE
0.0999144 216185 216 PLLTKLK
0.0749358 216185 162 STHIPSH
0.0624465 216185 135 MRQRRNR
0.0531952 216185 115 TQLPNIR
0.0518075 216185 112 SQQILNR
```

I want to search file2 column 4 strings for lines in file1 that contain matching column 4 strings. I would then like to output both the matching column 4 string and associated line's column 1 string for each file into a new file. Ex:

file1:

```
0.23961 216185 518 LIRRTSI
0.156348 216185 338 NTGSPYE
0.0999144 216185 216 PLLTKLK
```

file2:

```
0.3333333 300000 1000 MRQRRNR
0.2000000 300000 600 LIRRTSI
0.0450000 300000 135 TQLPNIR
```

Ideally my file3 output would be the following:

```
0.23961 LIRRTSI 0.2000000
```

or

```
0.23961 216185 518 LIRRTSI 0.2000000 300000 600 LIRRTSI
```

The most important thing is to at least have the matching string and column1 values output to a new file. I also have generated a list of column 4 strings via bash `comm` that are common between file 1 and file 2. Perhaps that is a good starting point? Any thoughts about how I can get this to work in bash or python. I am also willing to try any language if a solution presents itself.

Humbly,

J.M.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `join`

```
join -j4 -o 1.1 1.4 2.1 <(sort -k4 file1) <(sort -k4 file2)
```

- `-j4`:
  join two files on 4th column
- `-o 1.1 1.4 2.1`:
  output 1st column, 4th column from file1 and 1st column from file2

Answer (score 0):

A python solution:

```
f1 = {}
for line in open('file1'):
    f1[ line.split()[3] ] = line.strip()

for line in open('file2'):
    other = f1.get(line.split()[3], None)
    if other is not None:
        print '%s %s' % (other, line.strip())
```

Run on your two files, this produces:

```
0.23961 216185 518 LIRRTSI 0.2000000 300000 600 LIRRTSI
```

The above starts by going through file1 and creating a dictionary, called `f1`, which has as its keys your column 4 values.  As an example of one entry in the dictionary: `f1['NTGSPYE'] = '0.156348 216185 338 NTGSPYE'`

Next, it goes through file2 one line at a time looking for any line whose column 4 matches a key in dictionary `f1`.  If there is a match, it prints the corresponding lines from both files.

Note that the data in your files is separated by white space.  So, for any `line` for one of those files, `line.split()` is a list of the four values.  Because python starts counting from zero, the fourth column is in `line.split()[3]`.

**MORE:** A straightforward translation of the above to bash (v4 or better):

```
declare -A f1
while read -r one two three four
do
    f1["$four"]="$one"
done <file1

while read -r one two three four
do
    [ "${f1[$four]}" ] && echo "${f1[$four]} $four $one"
done <file2
```

Comment: All of the above solutions give ~the correct output. I think that I seriously underestimated the power of awk. Thanks for the added explanation John1024. Python has always eluded me and it helps hearing what the logic is behind a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

1) Output format: 0.23961 LIRRTSI 0.2000000

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$1;next}$4 in a {print $1, $4, a[$4]}' file2 file1
```

2) Output format:  0.23961 216185 518 LIRRTSI 0.2000000 300000 600 LIRRTSI

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$0;next}$4 in a {print $0,a[$4]}' file2 file1
```

Addition join command:

```
join -j4 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 <(sort -k4 file1) <(sort -k4 file2)

0.23961 216185 518 LIRRTSI 0.2000000 300000 600 LIRRTSI
```